# Laravel Mix Watch status loader works intermittently

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

When watching a project with laravel mix, "npm run watch", it used to show the green status bar all the time.  This was nice as when I hit save, it would quickly recompile just that one change.  It now only shows it like one out 30 times that command is run. It has to recompile the who project each time.  I cannot figure out whats the issue is here.

here's my package.json scripts section

````
   "dev": "npm run development",
   "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
   "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
   "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
   "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
   "prod": "npm run production",
   "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
 },```
````

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your command, except that you can use mix directly, try to use `mix watch` to see if it changes anything

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had debug set to true in my webpack config. Changing this to false now shows the status bar everytime.